# Best place to store custom files in Internal Storage

Tags: android, file

I have a custom database and files that I want to access. Currently am saving it in a folder on the root directory but the log says that I don't have permission to do so.

I don't want to save the files inside app assets folder. What is the best location to save the files in Internal Storage?

Comment: Store in `getExternalFilesDir()`

Answer (score 0):

create database with the name starting (.) in internal storage/sdcard. You can also create folder with (.) as first letter and put your database file in it. This'll be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

you should add permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Why `READ_PHONE_STATE`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
`Context.getExternalCacheDir()` or `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` The file will be store in the `SDCard/Android/data/data/<application package>/cache` or `SDCard/Android/data/data/<application package>/files`.
You should add the permission in AndroidManifest.xml
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
But don't need Android 6.0 Runtime Permissions.

For internal storage you can use Context.getCacheDir() or Context.getFilesDir().The file will be save in `data/data/<application package>/cache` or `data/data/<application package>/files`.For this place you don't need declare permission.

I think your database files are stored in the default location is the best.`data/data/<application package>/database`